# do we need to connect both sentences by using past perfect here

Tags: past-tense

Sorry I **saw** your message on here too late. I **had** over 50 orders of Tommy and the commie new 7" to send so I was pretty busy and as the payment of this order didn't arrive I didn't even check it

Can we deduct which action came first :the non seing message or the 50 orders to send.I would say the 50 orders to send. So would it be better to use past perfect (it is because he had 50 orders that he did not see the message) and to connect both sentences

I **had had** over 50 orders of Tommy and the commie new 7" to send so I **had been** pretty busy and as the payment of this order didn't arrive I didn't even check it

Comment: Native speakers/writers don't often use the past perfect in informal contexts, such as email, even if grammar books might suggest it's more correct. If you look at other questions about past perfect, you'll see many similar discussions. Here the time sequence is obvious from context, as you are able to infer.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the message arrived while the 50 orders etc were being prepared.

The original past tense is correct. The sentence is an apology, so it comes not too long after the event. The past perfect tense gives a sense of distance in time, which is wrong for an apology.

If you needed past perfect, you would also need to change "didn't arrive" and "didn't even check" to "hadn't arrived" and "hadn't even checked".

Comment: so it is only a question of distance in time and we can deduct that the non seeing message came after the beginning of the sending

Comment: @YvesLefol, past perfect reads like an incident in a biography. The sense of distance is both in time and in involvement.

Comment: you mean that the order of the events is not very important, may be she saw the message after or before  she received the fifty orders for the tommy or even simultaneously but  what is important is that she did not  take care of it.

Comment: We can't even be sure of the order of the events, and you are right, that is not the most important thing. The original statements  form an apology with an explanation, and it is important to get the apology right. For this the explanation needs to sound as though it is in the recent past, not in the historical past.

Comment: so it would l be better if she had written  i have seen your message too late . In this case we definitly know that the non seeing was after the sending and put as you said the "story" in recent past  (am I right ?)

Comment: No, _I have seen your message too late_ is not idiomatic. With _too late_, you need a simple past: _I saw your message too late_.

Comment: would it be better to use had not arrived